# how to make a soap call in c++

Tags: c++, xml, soap, client

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way of doing a c++ soap client that is independent of the wsdl.

What i need is something like to only know the name of the function and the list of parameters to send and send it and receive the soap response or something like this (i know that this is not as simple as it).

My idea is to do something like:
[SOAP Request and Response Read from and to file using libcurl - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4150710/soap-request-and-response-read-from-and-to-file-using-libcurl-c)
or
http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/16225/

Can you point me to the best way of doing this, or the best way is to use a library like gSoap and execute in the c++ code the c++ method of the classes that the gSoap generates?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what you are up to. If you need single request somewhere, curl (like you linked in the question) is appropriate. C++ contains C, so for once you don't really need C++ interface, though it would be nicer.

But if you need to do some serious work over SOAP, I would definitely recommend using [gSOAP](http://gsoap2.sourceforge.net/) or similar library. XML is rather tedious to work with. Serialization/deserialization is the easiest way to deal with it and C++ being statically typed, the serialization code has to be generated there from the schema. Which is just what gSOAP does. So I don't think there is an easier way than gSOAP.

Even if you don't have WSDL for it, I think it's easier to declare the methods you need in WSDL and generate appropriate serialization code from it than having to deal with XML by hand. In more dynamic languages the serialization/deserialization can be generated at runtime, but C++ does not allow that.

Comment: yes i know, i already know gSOAP, but what i'm asking if there is any easy way of doing this... maybe with some simple library... i already see libcurl that only make the connection, there is no help with xml messages. I need some abstract way of doing the communication... don't realy know how... but this is my question, is there any way?

Comment: @Nuno: I don't think there can be easier way than gSOAP. The easiest way to work with XML is using serialization/deserialization library and C++ being statically typed, the only way is to generate the (de)serialization code from given schema. Which is what gSOAP does. Any other method will mean more code and more bugs to be only caught during testing because it won't guarantee correct schema and types like the generated (de)serialization does.

Comment: @Nuno: Probably, you can use python. It has got everything very simple.

Answer (score 5):

Beware that gSOAP is GPL-licensed. A less restrictive alternative is **[Axis2/C++](http://axis.apache.org/axis/cpp/)**.

With Axis2/C++ you can generate stubs from a WSDL and use the generated classes to invoke the web service in your code

Generate stubs (yes Java, but this is a one-time action):

```
java org.apache.axis.wsdl.wsdl2ws.WSDL2Ws Calculator.wsdl -lc++ -sclient
```

Then use:

```
#include "Calculator.h" 
#include <stdio.h> 
int main() 
{ 
  Calculator c; 
  int intOut; 
  c.add(20, 40, intOut); 
  printf("result is = %d\n", intOut); 
  return 0; 
}
```

[More details here](http://axis.apache.org/axis/cpp/clientuser-guide.html)